# Vertices for a 20 sided DnD Dice

Tags: opengl, math, geometry, cartesian-coordinates

Does anyone know or know how I might get the vertices for a 20 sided dice?  I believe it is also known as a regular icosahedron.  I believe they have 12 vertices.  I don't mind the scale, although it would be nice if they were centered such that the center of the dice is the origin.  I'm thinking of something like

```
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
{x,y,z},
```

I'm planning on rendering it with OpenGL.  It doesn't have to include face data in triangle strip form, but that would be quite a bonus.

Also bonus question: does anyone know if the vertices are equal distance from the center?  Meaning they can all be normalized to 1?  I suspect they are.  If so, a normalized format would be great, but not necessary...I'd be happy with whatever data I can get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faces missing when drawing icosahedron in OpenGL following code in redBook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107006/faces-missing-when-drawing-icosahedron-in-opengl-following-code-in-redbook)

Comment: here [SE/SO: Faces missing when drawing icosahedron in OpenGL following code in redBook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43110844/2521214) is C++/OpenGL example

Comment: Thanks, more than I asked for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer partially. Yes, they are all the same distance from the center. This is true of all platonic solids. The vertices are given here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron

Comment: Useful info.  I will say that Rabbits comment has a fairly complete listing though if anyone is looking for code